# Plesk - Create domain when only adding subdomain

Tags: linux, webserver, hosting, plesk

I think I'm answering my own question here, but... If I'm just adding a subdomain to Plesk (10.4.4) do I add the main domain and then add a subdomain or just add the subdomain? There's a chance that there could be more subdomains, so I'm tempted to have the main domain where they can all sit under. The only thing is, I don't manage the main domain, so it would just be there for grouping purposes and there wouldn't be anything hosted there. As far as I'm aware there's not an option for that kind of setup so I just leave it as a normal domain. Yes?!

Thanks!

Darren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Generally you can create the main domain (i.e. `domain.com`) in Plesk even if you don't manage it. Your Plesk server simply will never receive a request for this site (as it is probably hosted somewhere else). That means whatever changes you apply to the main domain in Plesk - they will never impact the real domain. Still you will be able to add subdomains to the main domain in Plesk - but be sure to contact the main domain owner/manager to have them working appropriately (they will need to enable your subdomains in their DNS).

While *subdomains* in Plesk are slightly more limited than *domains*, most commercial offerings would allow larger number of *subdomains* and fewer *domains*. Unless this limitation is a concern , creating your sites as normal "*domains*" would be more convenient (more options available).